# classes depend on each other

Tags: c++, oop, class

consider these c++ fragments:

foo.h:

```
class foo
{
bar myobj;
};
```

bar.h:

```
class bar
{
foo *yourobj;
};
```

other file:

```
#include "foo.h" //because foo.h is included first bar will not be defined in foo.h
#include "bar.h"

foo container;

bar blah;
```

I know I didn't bother to write constructors and all that but you get the idea. Anyone know a way to remedy this situation?

Comment: Before you continue, try to compute `sizeof(foo)`.

Comment: Pointers are your solution here.

Comment: Basically what they are getting at is that it is impossible to have a foo inside a bar and a bar inside a foo at the same time, so you need to reconsider what you really want.

Comment: Every foo has a bar in it. Every bar has a foo in it. Uh oh.

Comment: You might want to reconsider your class schema because object aren't suppose to be needed within each others or that would make an infinite object creation loop

Comment: @Hugo Dozois in the real code I'm working on one of the members is a pointer. Basically foo has a bar and the bar has a member that points back to the foo that created it. I'm sorry about the confusion but the samples were just to outline my problem.

Comment: @PgrAm: But in that case there is no problem.

Comment: @PgrAm oh I see ! Looks legit then

Answer (score 7):

There are several common techniques to do this.

First, use forward declarations when you can. 
Second, if part of the circular dependency depends on functions in a class, make that class inherit from an "interface" class which provides declarations of those functions.
Lastly, use PIMPL (pointer to implementation details). Instead of listing all the fields in the class declaration, just include a pointer to the actual class data.

For example in `foo.h`

```
class foo_members;

class foo
{
    foo_members* opaque;
};
```

And in `foo.cpp`

```
#include "bar.h"
class foo_members{
    bar mybar;
};
```

Comment: What about ```foo_members``` destructor? I get warning ```note: neither the destructor nor the class-specific operator delete will be called, even if they are declared when the class is defined```.

Comment: Found the solution. Destructors have to be defined after bouth classes implementations are provided. Simply move destructor definition to .cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to make only one header that declares all your classes.

[classes.h]

```
class foo;
class bar;

class foo
{
    bar *FoosBar;
    int FooFunc(void);
};

class bar
{
    foo *BarsFoo;
    bool BarFunc(void);
}
```

[foo.cpp]

```
#include "classes.h"

int foo::FooFunc(void)
{
    // Reference FoosBar somewhere here or something maybe
    return 7;
}
```

[bar.cpp]

```
#include "classes.h"

bool bar::BarFunc(void)
{
    // Reference BarsFoo somewhere here or something maybe
    return true;
}
```

Comment: problem is I'm working on a large and complex piece of software that would easily become confusing if I started doing that.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean, but the circular dependency in itself is confusing to me. Try making the classes.h file ONLY have the forward declarations and not define any of the members of the classes
`class Foo;
class Bar;`

Then make sure both Foo.h and Bar.h include classes.h, and that Foo.cpp includes Bar.h, and Bar.cpp includes Foo.h